# How to disable user account in Firebase Web JS SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth to authenticate users using the Email/Password Method. Sometimes I detect spam users that create a lot of accounts from one IP address. I want to block them to protect my app.

I know that there is a method called "Disable User Account" in Firebase Console. I want to use it in my project.

I searched in Stack Overflow as well as the Firebase Docs and found that this only can be done in Admin SDK but I want to use it in the Firebase Web JS SDK. So is there a method to do that like `user.DisableAccount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to disable a specific user's account in the client-side Firebase SDKs, as that would be a security risk.

But if you look at the documentation for [updating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) with the Admin SDK, you'll see there is a property `disabled` that you can set to `true`.

From that moment in, that user won't be able to sign in or refresh their ID token. Their existing ID token is still valid though, and by default, that means it may take up to an hour for them to get signed out of your app. If that interval is a concern for your use case, have a look at the documentation on [managing user sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions), specifically the section on [detecting ID token revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation). While more work, this allows you more granular control of the expiration of the token.